# Running dotnet command in Azure Release not reporting error

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines

I am running an inline script in an Azure Pipelines Release that runs a custom dotnet .dll. Currently the app is throwing an exception, but the job appears to complete successfully. Is there anything special I need to do to report the error to the runner?

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run DbUp'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ...
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     7z x Database.zip
     dotnet database.dll
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/database'
    failOnStandardError: true
```

Comment: Does your application properly handle writing the exception to `stderr` or exit with a non-zero exit code? Or does it catch the exception and then print it to stdout?

Comment: I was under the assumption that the application throwing an unhandled exception would be enough. Let me try that.

Comment: @DanielMann this was the issue. If you would like to add it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application needs to properly handle writing the exception to `stderr` or exit with a non-zero exit code. If you just catch and print an exception, there's nothing indicating that an error condition occurred.